# How to change the emblem of a file-icon with C/C++ in GNOME?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I'm developing an App which works like Dropbox. I want to dynamically change the emblem of a file during synchronization. Like this:

[image: effect I want]

Is there any solution to this with Qt/C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need Qt for doing this.  But you will need C calls to do it.
You can create an extension for Nautilus and use NautilusInfoProvider and NautilusFileInfo, in
particular [`nautilus_file_info_add_emblem()`](http://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/libnautilus-extension-nautilus-file-info.html#nautilus-file-info-add-emblem).

If you implement NautilusInfoProvider and register your extension, then, Nautilus will
call [`nautilus_info_provider_update_file_info`](http://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/libnautilus-extension-nautilus-info-provider.html#nautilus-info-provider-update-file-info).  There you can implement the logic to check the file status and set the icon properly (with [`nautilus_file_info_add_emblem()`](http://developer.gnome.org/libnautilus-extension/stable/libnautilus-extension-nautilus-file-info.html#nautilus-file-info-add-emblem)).  However, I would recommend you to call that function when the application is idle.

Comment: How to access nautilus headers & APIs in Qt/C++ project. What are the libs & includepaths that are to be added to my porject file ?
Thanks.